# What is an example of the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: oop, definition, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle, design-principles

Can someone give me an example of the Single Responsibility Principle?  I am trying to understand what it means, in practice, for a class to have a single responsibility as I fear I probably break this rule daily.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659232/it-this-an-example-of-the-single-responsibility-principle

Comment: http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/oo-php-part-2-boring-oo-principles

Comment: Here's a good article about it. It help me a lot to figure out what Single Responsibility Principle mean [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611593/SOLID-Principles-Single-Respons](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611593/SOLID-Principles-Single-Respons)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [Solid description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Unless you ask for something more specific, it will be hard to help more.

Single responsibility is the concept of a Class doing one specific thing (responsibility) and not trying to do more than it should, which is also referred to as High Cohesion.

Classes dont often start out with Low Cohesion, but typically after several releases and different developers adding onto them, suddenly you'll notice that it became a monster or God class as some call it. So the class should be refactored.

Its hard to think of a good example, but one I can think of recently would be a class we have that manages different packet processing stages, a type of `Chain of Responsibility`. The initial intention of this class was to maintain a list of stages and to orchestrate calling packetProcess() on them. Well, it ended up that everybody added anything to do with the processing stages (since the manager class was an easy place to access the stages) to this manager class, especially stage configuration. The manager class no longer had a Single Responsibility, but instead was also responsible for making calls to the stages for configuration changes: thus the Cohesion had been reduced.

We ended up having to refactor the manager class, ripping out all the stage configuration and putting it in a factory, thus leaving the manager to do what it was intended to do.

Comment: I ran into this few weeks ago. I needed an Object Factory class which would create instances of different types of objects, Serialize them, Persist them to DB, etc. My first thought was creating a Factory class with a Serialize Method, but as a I read about the SRP, it made more sense having a Class exclusively dedicated to Serialize, one class to Persist objects in DB, etc. This makes your application much more maintainable and modular.

Comment: You still haven't provided a good explanation... you didn't even seem to understand the concept yourself... Remo's answer should be the selected one, not your vague one.  Also "Unless you ask for something more specific, it will be hard to help more" is a total cop-out and not helpfull at all, he was specific enough, give an example of SRP in classes. The only thing that would save this question is transforming your example into a psuedo code mve.

Answer (score 54):

The most effective way to break applications is to create [GOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) classes. Those are classes that keep track of a lot of information and have several responsibilities. One code change will most likely affect other parts of the class and therefore indirectly all other classes that use it. That in turn leads to an even bigger maintenance mess since no one dares to do any changes other than adding new functionality to it.

The following example is a TypeScript class that defines a `Person`, this class should not include email validation because that is not related with a person behaviour:

```js
class Person {
    public name : string;
    public surname : string;
    public email : string;
    constructor(name : string, surname : string, email : string){
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        if(this.validateEmail(email)) {
          this.email = email;
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Invalid email!");
        }
    }
    validateEmail(email : string) {
        var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
        return re.test(email);
    }
    greet() {
        alert("Hi!");
    }
}
```

We can improve the class above by removing the responsibility of email validation from the Person class and creating a new `Email` class that will have that responsibility:

```js
class Email {
    public email : string;
    constructor(email : string){
        if(this.validateEmail(email)) {
          this.email = email;
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Invalid email!");
        }        
    }
    validateEmail(email : string) {
        var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
        return re.test(email);
    }
}

class Person {
    public name : string;
    public surname : string;
    public email : Email;
    constructor(name : string, surname : string, email : Email){
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    greet() {
        alert("Hi!");
    }
}
```

Making sure that a class has a single responsibility makes it per default also easier to see what it does and how you can extend/improve it.

Comment: So now we'll get tons of single methos classes in our project?

Comment: Yes, you create more complex features by composing very simple single-concern entities.

Comment: I think it takes time to be good to understand SRP

Answer (score 4):

A class should have only one reason to change.

This principle states that if we have 2 reasons to change for a class, we have to split the functionality in two classes. Each class will handle only one responsibility and if in the future we need to make one change we are going to make it in the class which handles it.

If there are two different reasons to change, it is conceivable that two different teams may work on the same code for two different reasons. Each will have to deploy its solution, which in the case of a compiled language (like C++, C# or Java), may lead to incompatible modules with other teams or other parts of the application.

This principle is closely related to the concepts of coupling and cohesion. Coupling refers to how inextricably linked different aspects of an application are, while cohesion refers to how closely related the contents of a particular class or package may be.  All of the contents of a single class are tightly coupled together, since the class itself is a [single unit][1] that must either be entirely used or not at all.

My blog post on this:

http://javaexplorer03.blogspot.in/2016/12/single-responsibility-principle.html

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt0M_OHKhQE 
this video supports "A class should have only one reason to change"